# Subir imagenes a una base de datos mysql desde android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Uso estos dos métodos para intentar insertan una imagen a una base de datos desde una aplicación en Android, mi problema esta en que no se insertan las imágenes en la base de datos, el webservices si funciona por que lo utilizo para hacer pruebas en HTML, el que no funciona es el de la app, dice que el código es obsoleto, y no compila.

```
<?php         
include ("conexion.php");
$imagp= base64_decode($_POST['imgP']);
$imgv= base64_decode($_POST['imgV']);
$nombre=$_POST['nombre']; 
$query = "INSERT INTO imagen (imgP,imgV,nombre ) VALUES ('$imagp','$imgv','$nombre')";
 try {
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
$resultado = array();
    $resultado["success"] = false;  
    echo json_encode($resultado);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e ;
}
if ($resultado){
    echo " se inserto";
}
else{
    echo "no se inserto";
}

 ?>
```

Este es el que trate de usar para enviar el bitmap, pero esta obsoleto, el código no es mío.

```
private void enviar() throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.100.110/SS/agregar.php");
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mapa);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", imageName));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("igmP",
                Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }
```

Comment: Creo (corrijanme si es erróneo) que no se puede conectar directamente Android con MySQL. Tendrías que realizar la conexión mediante algún webservice. Yo te recomendaría usar REST.

Comment: Planteas mal tu pregunta. Para que te podamos ayudar, necesitas demostrar hasta donde has llegado y realizar preguntas a cerca de algo concreto, relacionado con la codificación, transmisión, almacenaje, tipos de datos a utilizar, etc.

Comment: Ya estoy usando un webservice, lo que ocupo es poder enviar el Bitmap hacia el webservice y que este las envié a la base de datos.

Comment: Hola @jaron. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Es un poco difícil adivinar qué estás intentando hacer. Sería bueno que aclares en la pregunta qué tipo de webservice es, cómo estás intentando conectarte y, sobre todo, que muestres los fragmentos de código (tanto de la app como del webmethod).

Comment: Estoy utilizando php para crear el webservice, mi app consiste en poder capturar una fotografía, y que esta se pueda subir a la base de datos.

Comment: @jaron, con ese método qué problema estás teniendo o cuál es el comportamiento érroneo? ¿obtienes un mensaje de error? ¿cuál es (letra por letra)? ¿la imagen se guarda pero está incorrecta? Por favor lee [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y añade los detalles relevantes que todavía faltan.

Comment: Formulé mejor mi problema, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo que no envies una imagen en bade 64.. en este link encuentras un completo ejemplo de subir una imagen desde Android a PHP.  Enviandola como un File. http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has intentado convertir la imagen a un String Base64 y enviarlo asi a la base de datos MySQL?

```
try
        {
            //Se obtiene el bitmap del image
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)_imgDenuncia.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            //se convierte a un arregleo de bytes
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            String imagen = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            _denuncia.setMimagen(imagen);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _denuncia.setMimagen("");
        }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Esto es algo similar al código que yo tengo, pero lo voy a probar así, gracias.

Comment: Amigo que quiere decir "_denuncia" es una variable? y que función cumple?

Comment: Hola. Es una instancia de una clase, dicha clase luego la serializo en un json y lo envio asi a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿De una clase? no comprendo muy bien.

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que yo tengo una clase que se llama Denuncia, a la cual le hago una instancia y le seteo la propiedad imagen que es de tipo string, el string Base64 que he generado, seguidamente esa clase la convierto en json para poderla enviar a traves del servicio rest. veo que vos estas intentando enviar un ArrayList. esa es la diferencia, vos envias un arreglo y yo una Clase.

Comment: Ya comprendí, gracias,